# Is there any replacement of /_ah/mapreduce/status dashboard in new appengine-mapreduce library

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce, pipeline

There used to be dashboard of all jobs in appengine-mapreduce library at `/_ah/mapreduce/status` URL. If I use `com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-mapreduce:0.2` and navigate to the `/mapreduce/status` page I get `RuntimeException: Not Implemented`. Has been the dashboard moved to `appengine-pipeline` project or is it simply dropped?

If there isn't any dashboard out of box what is the best way to create similar one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implemented in Mapreduce 0.4 and up.